# Spring Cloud application and end-to-end automatic testing

Tags: testing, automated-tests, spring-cloud, microservices, end-to-end

I have an application based on Spring Cloud. It means I am using Eureka server service discovery and the system has couple of microservices. Can you recommend me any approach how to make automatic ent-to-end tests across my system? I have Docker so It is easy to start system. Of course I know SOAPui etc. but is here any way how to write these tests at Java and keep them in the project?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered not doing end to end testing and do contract testing instead? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/

Comment: Yes, I have but I'd like to test whole infrastructure instead of just contracts.

Comment: The problem is that I want to test some behavior of service discovery therefore Spring Cloud Contract is not suit for it

Comment: You can use sc contract to mock out service discovery. Also you can use sc contract to register stubs in real service discovery tool.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I want to mock just data and do real tests of  infrastructure.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. You can do that. Register stubs as apps in a real piece of infrastructure (for example Eureka) - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html#_stub_runner_boot_with_service_discovery

Comment: I will check it. Thx